# need to do calculation in android

Tags: android, addition

I am newbie to android and trying to develop Income Tax Calculator as a part of my project. I have around 8 fields on a page and i want to sum up all those fields and display it in textview. I have written following code for that:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Tab2 extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      public  int tot_ded=0;
      public  int value1=0;
      public  int value2=0;
      public  int value3=0;
      public  int value4=0;
      public  int value5=0;
      public  int value6=0;
      public  int value7=0;
      public  int value8=0;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
          EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtHRA);
          EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt80C);
          EditText e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txthome_loan_inte);
          EditText e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtmedi_ins_self);
          EditText e5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtmedi_ins_depe);
          EditText e6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtmedi_reim);
          EditText e7=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtcon_allo);
          EditText e8=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtprof_tax); 
          TextView Textv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txttotal_dedu);
        //When  I remove this code from comment, it stops my app.
        /* value1=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
        value2=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());

            value3=Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString());
            value4=Integer.parseInt(e4.getText().toString());

            value5=Integer.parseInt(e5.getText().toString());
            value6=Integer.parseInt(e6.getText().toString());

            value7=Integer.parseInt(e7.getText().toString());
             value8=Integer.parseInt(e8.getText().toString());


        tot_ded=value1+value2+value3+value4+value5+value6+value7+value8;*/
        e7.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    //Textv1.setText(tot_ded);
                }
            }
        });

     }

}
```

Can anybody help me out. I know question is childish but I really dont know what to do. Pls help me out.

Comment: Help you to do what? Where are you stuck? Are you expecting a result which isn't coming? What is that expectation?

Answer (score 0):

```
  e8.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                value1=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString()); 
                value2=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString()); 

                value3=Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString()); 
                value4=Integer.parseInt(e4.getText().toString()); 

               value5=Integer.parseInt(e5.getText().toString()); 
               value6=Integer.parseInt(e6.getText().toString()); 

               value7=Integer.parseInt(e7.getText().toString()); 
               value8=Integer.parseInt(e8.getText().toString()); 


            tot_ded=value1+value2+value3+value4+value5+value6+value7+value8;
                Textv1.setText(tot_ded); 
            } 
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You first need to add a button to sum up all the edit texts.
2. Set InputType of every edittext to number like`android:inputType="number"`

3.on button click check for every edittext for empty value like

```
if(et1.getText().toString.equals("")||et2.getText().toString.equals("")||et3.getText().toString.equals(""))
                {

                   Toast.makeText("No value should be empty");

                }
                else
                {
                     value1=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString()); 
                        value2=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString()); 

                        value3=Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString()); 
                        value4=Integer.parseInt(e4.getText().toString()); 

                       value5=Integer.parseInt(e5.getText().toString()); 
                       value6=Integer.parseInt(e6.getText().toString()); 

                       value7=Integer.parseInt(e7.getText().toString()); 
                       value8=Integer.parseInt(e8.getText().toString()); 


                    tot_ded=value1+value2+value3+value4+value5+value6+value7+value8;
                        Textv1.setText(tot_ded); 


                }
```

Hope this will work....

Answer (score -1):

if you do this

```
value1=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
```

and all the code after that when you remove the comments you are getting absolutely nothing from the editText and you cannot

```
Integer.parseInt("");
```

it will throw a NumberFormatException

id say your best bet is to make a button and make sure all the edit texts actually have int's in them before you do your calculation